# CppCheck: Variable 'bla' is not assigned a value

Tags: c++, coding-style, cppcheck

running CppCheck over my codebase produces some style warnings. E.g. in

```
void foo(int& x)
{
  x = 0; 
}
void bar()
{
  int y;
  foo(y);
}
```

it gives me

```
Variable 'y' is not assigned a value
```

It's the same with code like

```
 char buffer[160];
 i+=sprintf(buffer,"%2.2ld.",ymd.monthday);
```

Is this a problem with my code or is it a problem with CppCheck? (How) should I fix it?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/2535) in CppCheck and the good news is that it has already been fixed!

You can either grab the [latest code](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/) and build your own version or wait for v1.48 to be released. Version 1.48 is planned to be released on April 9th according to [the wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of CppCheck. Your code is fine (at least the given one).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `y` as an 'out' parameter, but CppCheck is not able to determine that. It is better to initialize the `y` at the time of definition with `int y = 0;` so that in future if somebody tries to use the parameter `x` in `foo` they will not get uninitialized value.